# Garbage collection monitoring - when to alert?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, spring-boot, nagios, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot exposes the following 4 metrics related to GC. I am configuring Nagios to send two alerts (Warning and Critical) when they reach certain value. I am wondering what that thresholds should be? I have a 16GB heap.

- gc.ps_marksweep.count
- gc.ps_marksweep.time
- gc.ps_scavenge.count
- gc.ps_scavenge.time

Comment: The answers would really depend on the tolerance level of your users to the induced lag that a GC would cause.  Dial-up users often have a much higher tolerance for lag, then say, someone using the application over a 1GB wired connection.